# How can I show the IntelliSense autocomplete dropdown when using GitHub Copilot in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I have a problem using VS Code with Copilot and Copilot Chat.

When I write a function I would like to view the properties of an object with the "intellisense autocomplete dropdown":

[image: intellisense autocomplete dropdown]

When I'm using Copilot, by default, it will first suggest the "intellisense autocomplete dropdown". Like this:

[image: copilot]

When I now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> it will hide the copilot suggestion and "intellisense autocomplete dropdown". This is what I want. But since Copilot Chat is a thing, it will now show the Copilot Chat thing:

[image: Copilot Chat]

How can I show or force show the "intellisense autocomplete dropdown"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Trigger Suggest` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), or whatever keyboard shortcut is bound to that command. You can [rebind the keyboard shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) to your liking too (the command ID is `editor.action.triggerSuggest`).